# Working with Dates with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say there is an account, on which I have to incur a charge every year till date.

So for each charge incurred a row is generated in table mentioning its date.
unfortunately, due to some reason a charge is missed to applied in a particular year and no row is generated for that year.

So my aim is to find all those account for which the charge was missed and its year.

Comment: What is the structure of your table, and what is your current query that is not working?

Comment: acctno chargetype date
1           xyz             20-01-2014
1           abc             20-01-2015
1           xyz             20-01-2017
2           xyz             20-01-2015
2           xyz             20-01-2016
2           xyz             20-01-2017

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Answer (score 0):

The solution below will find years with missing payments, but only between years that show payments in your table. It will **not** find payments missed in the first year, or missed payments that were never followed by payments that were received. (So, for example, if the payments should have been from 2010 to 2016, and the table only shows 2012, 2013, 2015 then the solution will find 2014, but it will not find 2010, 2011 and 2016). The data in your table is not sufficient to find those missed payments; also, if an account should have had payments, but no payments were **ever** made, then that account will not exist in your table at all, so the solution has no way of catching those accounts.

```
with
     test_data ( acctno, chargetype, dt ) as (
       select 1, 'xyz', to_date('20-01-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 1, 'abc', to_date('20-01-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 1, 'xyz', to_date('20-01-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 2, 'xyz', to_date('20-01-2015', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 2, 'xyz', to_date('20-01-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
       select 2, 'xyz', to_date('20-01-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual
     )
-- End of test data (not part of the solution)
-- Query begins below this line; use your actual table name instead of "test_data"
select acctno, min_year + level - 1 as yr
from   (
         select   acctno, 
                  min(extract(year from dt)) min_year, 
                  max(extract(year from dt)) max_year
         from     test_data
         group by acctno
       )
where (acctno, min_year + level - 1) not in ( select acctno, extract(year from dt)
                                              from   test_data
                                            )
connect by level <= max_year - min_year + 1
       and prior acctno = acctno
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
;

ACCTNO    YR
------  ----
     1  2016
```

Comment: Kudos for a well detailed answer to an inadequate question.